# How do i mark directory as source in vscode? Have tried all possible solutions nothing works

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I have the following structure in vscode:

```
development
    .vscode
        |____settings.json
    src 
      extract
         |___extract.py 
      utils 
         |___ranking.py 
      build
         |__model.py 
      words.txt
      .env
```

i wish to run extract.py and i get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.ranking'
```

and some of my **extract.py** looks like:

```
import utils.ranking as qr
f = open('../words.txt')

f = f.readlines()
```

these are the top few lines. **ranking.py contains a function ranking**

Now i know this code works as it does in pycharm. The only thing is that i have not marked a directory as source here as i would in pycharm. So i have followed the steps on stack overflow and created a .env file under src folder and it looks like:

```
PYTHONPATH=./src
```

I then edit the settings.json so it looks like:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/conda/envs/test01/bin/python",
    "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"
}
```

Then when i run extract.py i still get same error. What is causing this? What else can i do. New to vscode!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set it like this:

```
  "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",  //not need
  "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
  }
```

The settings you have set, only work in the debugging mode. You can have a look at the [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_use-of-the-pythonpath-variable).

> PYTHONPATH can be set through the terminal settings
> (**terminal.integrated.env.***) and/or within an **.env file**.
>
> When the **terminal settings** are used, **PYTHONPATH affects any tools that**
> **are run within the terminal** by a user, as well as any action the
> extension performs for a user that is routed through the terminal **such**
> **as debugging.** **However**, in this case when the extension is performing
> an action that isn't routed through the terminal, such as the use of a
> linter or formatter, then this setting will not have an effect on
> module look-up.
>
> When PYTHONPATH is set using an .env file, it will affect anything the
> extension does on your behalf and actions performed by the debugger,
> but it will not affect tools run in the terminal.
>
> **If needed, you can set PYTHONPATH using both methods.**

Comment: when i use your update should i remove the python.envFile line?

Comment: @Maths12 That's the default setting, you can modify it to some other place, if you do not want to modify it, you can just remove it.

Comment: hi it hasn't helped as it doesn't detect my modules i created